# Notebook shutdowns abruptly during gaming in CPU usage=28%, CPU Temperature=100 (C)

Tags: cpu, overheating

my notebook shutdowns very abruptly while playing a video game for approximately 30 min. I decided to log my CPU sensors and other measurable data about CPU to find out what is going on.

**Memory usage (%)**: *initial value = 40*; jumps to 95-100 very very fast at the start and remains there.

**CPU usage(%)**: *initial value=5*; goes to 25 very fast and fluctuates between 15 and 35.

**CPU Temperature (C)**: *initial value=45*; goes up very slowly and steady to 100 at the end (shutdown moment)

so as you may guess it seems we have a over-heating in CPU. but **I want to be sure**, is 100 (C) too high? is there any way that I can find out if my System turned off itself to protect CPU from damage? something such as freamware configuration? and What should I do? thank you!

**My CPU = Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-3610QM CPU @ 2.30GHz.**

**My Notebook = Asus n46VZ**

****UPDATE!:****

just the moment that my system is going to turn off (maybe 0.5 seconds before turn off) the fan's sound (noise) goes up very fast for the last moment. in fact I always know that my system is going to shutdown just 0.5 seconds earlier.

Comment: It should not get that hot at 15-35% CPU.  It may be the thermal paste was insufficient or dried up. It could be the fan is clogged with dust. You may want to take it to a local computer store to have it cleaned and the CPU properly re-seated with good thermal compound

Comment: Enough positive feedback to post as an answer

Comment: sorry for bad English!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should not get that hot at 15-35% CPU. (Note: 100 degrees C is too hot for any personal computer I know of).

It may be the thermal paste was insufficient or dried up. It could be the fan is clogged with dust.

You may want to take it to a local computer store to have it cleaned and the CPU properly re-seated with good thermal compound

You can check CPU temp with RealTemp if you wish. It provides good information on your system.

https://www.techpowerup.com/download/techpowerup-real-temp/

But the system will protect the CPU from damage if it shuts down from overheating.

Comment: I am looking for an answer to my second question.

Comment: I added information to my answer above.

Comment: One good thing to do to prevent an abrupt shutdown is to set your cooling mode to Passive in your Power options. That way, your CPU will start throttling down before you reach the T-junction. You keep going like that, your goose will be cooked long before Thanksgiving...